# localStorage after updated web site is reset

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

In my react app I have 12 buttons and an array which has a length of 12 that is filled with the plus character: `.fill("+");`.

I have function that after clicking on one of these buttons that changes the Array(i) to ("-");

I need to save this Array in localStorage, but for this I create:

```
localStorge = localStorage.spots(spots=is my varryable in code)  = JSON.stringify(Array(12).fill("-"));
```

I tap on my button and may local storage changed ==cool = everything works

but after reload my web my Array in local storage =

```
JSON.stringify(Array(12).fill("-"));
```

it is logic because I write it in beginning of the code, but I don't need it. I need to create local storage `(Array(12).fill("-"))` change it after clicking on my buttons and after reload local storage stayed changed.

app.js

```
export default class Hall extends React.Component {
   
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      spots:JSON.parse(localStorage.spots),
    
    }
  }
  handlClick(i) {
    const spots =this.state.spots.slice();
    spots[i]="бронь";
    localStorage.spots=JSON.stringify(spots); 
    const color = this.state.color.slice();
    color[i]="danger";

   
    this.setState({
      spots:JSON.parse(localStorage.spots),
      color: color,

    });

  }

  renderSquare(i) {
    return (
    <Spot
    onClick={()=> this.handlClick(i)}
    value={this.state.spots[i]}

    />
    );
  }

  render() {

    return (

      <div className="BySpot">
          <div className="date"></div>
          <div className="inSpot">
          <div className="screen">screen</div>
          <div className="exit">exit</div>
        
        <div className="board-row1">
        board-row1
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row2">
        board-row2
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row3">
        board-row3
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row4">
        board-row4
          {this.renderSquare(9)}
          {this.renderSquare(10)}
          {this.renderSquare(11)}
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

index.js


function Main(props) {
    localStorage.spots = JSON.stringify(Array(12).fill("своб"));
    return (
        <main className="main" >
       <Nav />
     
     <WrapMain />

        </main>

    )

};


    ReactDOM.render(
        <Main />,document.getElementById("root")
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a wrong syntax, you can't add value in localStorage that way. Try this:

```
localStorage.setItem('spots', JSON.stringify(spots))
```

and then you can get from localStorage

```
const spots = localStorage.getItem('spots')
```

and parse the `spots` variable if you need.

Here you can read more in docs.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage